# Black screen when loading linux kernel on laptop

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, grub, lfs

I built the linux kernel in LFS and grub works, but when I load the linux kernel the screen just becomes black and nothing happens after that. What should I do? Im on a laptop btw if that matters. Here is the grub configuration:

```
# Begin /boot/grub/grub.cfg
set default=0
set timeout=5

insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root=(hd0,2)

if loadfont /boot/grub/fonts/unicode.pf2; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  insmod all_video
  terminal_output gfxterm
fi

menuentry "GNU/Linux, Linux 5.19.2-lfs-11.2"  {
  linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.2-lfs-11.2
}

menuentry "Firmware Setup" {
  fwsetup
}
```

/boot/vmlinux* is the kernel image file on the second partition of the first harddrive

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your laptop is not expecting to work with external monitor, look at your functional keys (usually it is Fn+F8).
2. When looking at black screen (once you sure that boot up ended and HDD no longer flashing). Try hitting Alt+F1, Alt+F2, etc - this could bring you to a text console. In this case the problem most likely with incorrect video driver. Run `X -configure` and you would have `/root/xorg.conf.new` file. Edit it - reducing driver from proprietary to a more generic one and copy it to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.
3. Try booting from LiveUSB. If successful - the problem is in your new kernel, fix it while booted from LiveUSB.

Comment: method 2 does not work and method 3: ive been using liveusb (os on an usb) all along but it doesnt work